# Is there a way to write a single line javadoc comment, like in doxygen /**<*/

Tags: javadoc

I would like to comment a variable like I used to do in doxygen and I wonder if there is a way to comment variables after declaring them in the same line. (I've never used javadoc before =/ ).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, you can use `/** comment */`.

Comment: Thanks, I thought it would be something different, like the two different ways in doxygen.

Comment: Does /** comment */ have to be before the item it is commenting? Doxygen allowed me to comment inline. "int x; ///< commented"

Comment: Javadoc /** comment */ should be before commented element.

Comment: no, it doesn't work if on the same line: pointing the mouse over the keyword doesn't show it in the popup!

Comment: @tontonCD I usually add `/** Javadoc */` in previous line of code, for which javadoc is prepared. And it works fine for me in Eclipse - popup is displayed when mouse is over the keyword like method name or variable name.